# nodejs not responsing to requests remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httpresponse, remote-server

I have just installed node.js 0.8.2 on a remote, shared server (I cannot get newer version). So far, all I have been able to is log to the console after running `node file.js`. However, I want to be able to get a server working (obviously) but it isn't working. This is the code I tried to run:

```
//run with node.js
console.log('hello working thingy');
var http=require('http');
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log('requested');
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
});
server.listen(1234,'127.0.0.1');
```

When I run it in putty it says `hello working thingy`, but when I go to `mydomain.com:1234` nothing happens in the browser and `requested` is not logged to the console. I have also tried replacing `'127.0.0.1` with `mydomain.com` and also leaving that argument out altogether. What do I do to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server.listen(1234, '0.0.0.0');` is what you want there if you are going to connect remotely. `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address which is for same-computer local connections only. `0.0.0.0` means "listen on all IP addresses".

Comment: So the code is now correct. Next you need to troubleshoot the firewall on the OS and maybe also a firewall operated by your hosting provider. It's annoying to answer that on stackoverflow though as it's a back and forth thing. Most likely it's an OS-level firewall and you need to open port 1234. Use a web search. This is an extremely common thing for beginners to struggle with.

Comment: thanks, the firewall was the issue. I contacted support, they opened a port, and with 0.0.0.0 as the host it works. Thanks!